# Google Map through TypeError: b.P is not a function error

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I am trying to use infowindow in google map. Map is implementing but whenever I used to click on any marker there is always an error in console "TypeError: b.P is not a function"
Following is the code I am using.

```
 var mapOptions_map2;
function initialize_map2() {

  var locations_map2 = eval(document.getElementById('locations').value);
  mapOptions_map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('fullmap_view'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: mapcenter,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });
  var contentString = 'some content';
  var infowindow_map2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 200
  });

  var marker_map2, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations_map2.length; i++) {  
      marker_map2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_map2[i][1], locations_map2[i][2]),
        map: mapOptions_map2
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker_map2, 'click', (function(marker_map2, i) {
         return function() {
            infowindow_map2.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow_map2.open(map, marker_map2);
         }
        })(marker_map2, i));
      }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: This trailing comma here won't help (and will probably throw an error in IE): `mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,`

Comment: After removing that comma I am still getting error "TypeError: g.e is undefined" by clicking any of marker. One point is important here is by commenting (removing) return function(){ and the closing braket of this function. One infowindow is always by default on display. But after closing that and then clicking on any of marker there is again the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "map" variable in your code. You want mapOptions_map2 instead:

```
        infowindow_map2.open(map, marker_map2);
```

should be:

```
        infowindow_map2.open(mapOptions_map2, marker_map2);
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_InfoWindow.html)

Comment: That is a really great effort, by making change as per your direction. there is an error in console "TypeError: b.P is not a function (92 out of range 47)" sometimes there is 94 instead of 92. I am surprised that in your example my code is working fine then why not it is working on my side?

Comment: Probably because your code is not the same as my example.  You didn't post complete code, perhaps there is an error outside of what you posted.

Comment: i have a map variable still i am getting the same error. what would be the problem??

Comment: @Dimple can you paste your code here if your problem is not resolved yet

Comment: That would be a different question in all likelihood.  The code should be posted in a new question.